# Special Character does not displays in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have asp.net grid view which binds data from xml file but in the grid i am unable to see the special character which is present in the xml file. The actual value e.g. **4-Â­-0444** got modified to **4-Â­0444** due to html encoding. Is there any way to stop this encoding process globally in the website.

**Asp.net Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="BillNo" HeaderText="BillNo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PageNo" HeaderText="PageNo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Activity" HeaderText="Activity" HtmlEncode="false" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code**

```
DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
dsResult.ReadXml(new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml")));
if (dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dsResult.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
e.Row.Cells[2].Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[2].Text));      
}
}
```

XML

```
<Tenders>
  <Ravina>
    <BillNo>1</BillNo>
    <PageNo>10</PageNo>
    <Activity>Metals</Activity>
  </Ravina>
  <Ravina>
    <BillNo>2</BillNo>
    <PageNo>20</PageNo>
    <Activity>Formworks</Activity>
  </Ravina>
  <Ravina>  
   <BillNo>3</BillNo>
  <PageNo>30</PageNo>
  <Activity>4-Â­-0444</Activity>
  </Ravina>
</Tenders>
```

**Final Output**

```
BillNo  PageNo  Activity
1        10     Metals
2        20     Formworks
3        30     4-Â­0444 (This value got modified, actual value <Activity>4-Â­-0444</Activity> )
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it specifically the GridView? What happens if you add that exact value to the page in the apsx?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If hard code the value in the html then output will be same ie "4-Â­0444". But databases support values like "4-Â­-0444".

Answer (score 0):

if you use a templated column, and drop in a label, then it probably will work.

so, try this:

In markup, remove the data bound, and add this:

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Actitivy") %>' >
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Then in row data bound, try this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
            lbl1.Text = gData["Activity"].ToString();
        }
    }
```